# Problems downloading expansion files

Tags: file, download, expansion

I've uploaded my app to google. It has been published. My main exp file was uploaded with app version code 2 and it still bears the same name. My main app is right now at version code 4 and is still using the main.2 exp file.

I've already tested the file with my app through debug.

I've created a test account and i'm signed in on the device with that account and tried downloading 20 minutes after creating that test account.

I believe my file size is correct too. I'm using the the size from the properties 155,630,535 bytes and set it to 155630535L. There is another one called as size on disk which I'm not using.

I've uploaded my apk over 12 hours ago.

Really don't know where I'm going wrong. The only thing I wonder about is my version name which is 1.13. Do I need to use this anywhere?

I'm having problems downloading my expansion files. Initially I was getting 'download failed because you may not have purchased this app'. Now after recompiling (export file) the apk file and uninstalling it and reinstalling it to my device, I've uploaded it to my publish account and now I get 'resources could not be found'. Please help...

Answer (score 2):

ok. I've resolved my issues after a lot of struggling by myself.

First, it's the size of the file in bytes only and not the size of the file in bytes on the disk.

Secondly, they have moved the test account into settings. You need to create a test account.

Thirdly, the app needs to be saved in draft mode. The expansion files will not download while testing using the test account, if the app has been published.

I hope this will help someone.

Comment: hey, my app is in draft mode, I have placed the test account i have putted the correct size and still get the same error.
Any other ideas?

Comment: draf mode is also not working anymore, you now need to publish the app in either alpha or beta to properly test. See my anwer for more information about apk expansion files.

Answer (score 0):

Some helfull information for people that end up here in this post since there are some things that changed in the way apk expansions work and also if you are using Android Studio to make the libraries work.

**NOTE 1**

You can't use draft anymore as the link to get the expansion file won't be active yet. You have to upload a version to Alpha or Beta first with expansion file. (adding an expansion file is only possible from the second apk you upload and up) So make sure you see the apk expansion file listed when you click the details in the developer publish section under APK.

**NOTE 2**

If you are using android studio and want to make use of the downloader library don't just copy the package name and java files into your own app src directory. Import the downloader library in eclipse and choose export => gradle build files. Afterwards you can import the library as a module in android studio.

**NOTE 3**

Not sure of this but I also think it's neccesary to download the app atleast once through the play store and have access to it with the account on your test device. So if you are working with alpha create a google+ test group and add yourself or other test devices to it.

**BTW**

With these libraries it's pretty easy to implement the apk expansion download just make sure:

1. your activity (the one where you want to implement the downloading
   of the expansion pack when the downloading has not been done
   automatically) implements IDownloaderClient.
2. you set up the service & receiver and set them up in your manifest.
3. The BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY in the service class is correct. Upload the
   first apk => look in Services and API's in the developer console
   under your app => License code for this app.

This code is used to see if the expansion file can be found on the device:

```
boolean expansionFilesDelivered() {
    for (XAPKFile xf : xAPKS) {
        String fileName = Helpers.getExpansionAPKFileName(this, xf.mIsMain, xf.mFileVersion);
        Log.i(TAG, "Expansion filename " +fileName);
        if (!Helpers.doesFileExist(this, fileName, xf.mFileSize, false))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

It uses the class XAPKS wich represents an expansion file, be it either a main or patch file, having a certain filesize(bytes) and associated with a apk version (the one it was first added in).

```
private static class XAPKFile {
        public final boolean mIsMain; // true
        public final int mFileVersion; //example 4
        public final long mFileSize; //example 126515695L
        // example => main expansion that was first introduced in apk version 4 and is 126515695 bytes in size

        XAPKFile(boolean isMain, int fileVersion, long fileSize) {
            mIsMain = isMain;
            mFileVersion = fileVersion;
            mFileSize = fileSize;
        }
    }
```

Its also quite easy to read movie files and other stuff directly from the expansion file using the zip tools that google has provided (com.android.vending.zipfile).

First get the expansionfile using the methods provided in the library, the paremeters are integers that represent your main expansion apk version (the apk version where the expansion pack you need was first added) and the patch apk version.

```
ZipResourceFile expansionFile = APKExpansionSupport.getAPKExpansionZipFile(context, APKX_MAIN_APK, APKX_PATCH_APK);
```

**Video**

For playing video directly from this zipresourcefile:

```
AssetFileDescriptor a = expansionFile.getAssetFileDescriptor(pathToFileInsideZip);
```

Now from this assetFileDescriptor you can get a FileDescriptor and use this in your mediaplayer, the correct syntax to get your mediaplayer to play the video also needs the second and third parameter.. Be it the startoffset and length you can get from the AssetFileDescriptor.

```
player.setDataSource(a.getFileDescriptor(), a.getStartOffset(), a.getLength());
```

**Other**

For all the other stuff (like images) you can just get an inputstream of the zipresourcefile:

```
expansionFile.getInputStream(pathToFileInsideZip);`
```

ALSO make sure you don't compress the videos in the zip for this to work!
for example not to compress .mp4 files:

```
zip -n .mp4 -r zipfile.zip . -x ".*" -x "*/.*"
```